# cannot run pip in win10

Tags: python, pip

when I run $pip in windows10, it shows:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

but when I run $pip3, it shows the detail successful.

```
Usage:
  pip <command> [options]
...
```

I downloaded the python in custom directory
C:\any_program_related\python\Scripts

I already clicked the "add path" during in installation on python. How come the $pip does not run properly? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pip` doesn't exist you could try `alias pip=$(which pip3)` ?

Comment: it solves the problem!! thank you!!